# Creating xml file in django

Tags: python, django

How can i create a xml file in django where the file is to contain objects from a queryset?

```
def my_serialize(request):
    from django.core import serializers
    data = serializers.serialize('xml', Student.objects.filter(Q(name__startswith='A')), 
            fields=('name','dob'))
    from django.core.files import File
    f = open('content.xml', 'w')
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(data)
    myfile.close()
```

After i call the above function, my content file remains empty, there is no data that gets written in it.

Comment: You don't create XML files in Django. You create XML files in Python.

Comment: Is your file empty because 'data' is empty? Or because file writing is failing? Run this from the django shell and investigate if the serializer call is returning XML. And if the query is returning any objects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("xml", SomeModel.objects.all())
```

Take a look at the [Serialization documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/).

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to dump objects for later retrieval. That's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use version 1.3, so I'm not sure how it works, but could it be that the file is not actually being opened? Could adding `myfile.open('w')` work? Of course, this may be handled in the File class's **init** function. Anyway, try giving it a shot and commenting your results.

Update:
BTW, I came up with the idea from looking at the docs. Maybe they'll be able to help too.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/file/